# How to wait while evaluating an expression with emacsclient?

Tags: emacsclient

I use `emacsclient` regularly to open files. In order to open files owned by root, it is necessary to use tramp. As far as I know this requires the use of the `eval` option of `emacsclient`.

```
emacsclient --eval '(find-file "/sudo::/etc/motd")'
```

But this command behaves as if I specify the option `no-wait`, because the evaluation returns after the file has been opened.

Which expression needs to be evaluated in order to wait till the file has been closed?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I am able to use `emacsclient /sudo::/etc/motd` which waits.

Comment: @amitp Thanks! I was not aware that I can use the tramp url directly. That solves my problem.